# How to make union all command using Yii framework command DAO object

Tags: php, mysql, yii, union, union-all

I am trying to make a union of a few tables data into one query using. I am using Yii framework (v1.15). I have done it like this and this worked fine:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->select('something')->from('somewhere');
$command->union($sql);
```

This produces something like this:

> SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOMEWHERE UNION (SELECT ....)

But union merges duplicate row values. I need to combine all of the data using `UNION ALL`, but I can't find anything about how to do it in the 
[documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand).

Maybe some of you how can I do it using the yii database object? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii `1.x.x`'s query builder, `UNION ALL` is not supported. You can change it to:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT something FROM somewhere UNION ALL({$sql})");
```

Another way is to override `union()` and `buildQuery()` methods in `CDbCommand` command or create `unionAll()` method by inheriting `CDbCommand`.

---

Another **dirty** way would be:

```
$sql=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('something')->from('somewhere')->union("SELECT something FROM somewhere")->getText();
```

Which is equal to:

```
SELECT `something` FROM `somewhere` UNION ( SELECT something FROM somewhere)
```

Then:

```
$sql=  str_replace('UNION', 'UNION ALL', $sql);
```

Or using regular expression:

```
$command->text = preg_replace('/\sUNION\s/', ' UNION ALL ', $command->text);
```

Which is equal to:

```
SELECT `something` FROM `somewhere` UNION ALL ( SELECT something FROM somewhere)
```

Then, pass it through `createCommand()` method.

Comment: Well the dirty way can make some unexpected results, but it may save some time, I think I'll use the dirty way, but use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace` and search for whole words,   hopefully lower possibility of replacing wrong words :) thank you for clarification

Comment: In my case union not work at all. When I do `$cmd1->union($cmd2->getText())` I have a problem with parameters inside $cmd2: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`